# Login without database using just PHP it's safe?

Tags: php, security

i have made this simple login page without any database

```
<?php session_start(); 
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
$logins = array('123' => '123');
$Username = isset($_POST['Username']) ? $_POST['Username'] : '';
$Password = isset($_POST['Password']) ? $_POST['Password'] : '';

if (isset($logins[$Username]) && $logins[$Username] == $Password){
$_SESSION['UserData']['Username']=$logins[$Username];
header("location:index.php");
exit;
} else {
$msg="<span style='color:red'>Invalid Login Details</span>";
}
}
?>
```

html in the same page

```
<form action="" method="post" name="Login_Form">
  <table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" class="Table">
    <?php if(isset($msg)){?>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="top"><?php echo $msg;?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top"><h3>Login</h3></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right" valign="top">Username</td>
      <td><input name="Username" type="text" class="Input"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Password</td>
      <td><input name="Password" type="password" class="Input"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> </td>
      <td><input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Login" class="Button3"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

i want to know if this login page it's safe and hard to hack it !
if you have any adea to secure this page login please give it to me 
Thank you in advance

Comment: `123` for username and password will be pretty quick to brute force. What do you define as "hack"?

Comment: start by hashing your passwords using password_hash() and then comparing them with password_verify()

Comment: @user3783243 i will change 123 to another strong password but i want to know if there is a string can be used in this form to crypte this password

Comment: You can use basic http authentication if you want to restricted your page but if you have a multiple user with multiple username password then you have to use db

Comment: @rowmoin i have just one user because of that i don't want to use database

Comment: Ok then you should use http basic authentication it's standard and secure mechanism

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use a database or put the password in the script, the security issues are the same. You should hash the password in the script, just like you would if it were in a database.

Comment: @rowmoin There's little security difference between using a form and basic authentication. And it doesn't change how he does the authentication in the script.

Comment: @rowmoin i want just to be sure that there is no one can bypass my login

Comment: @Barmar yes you are right.